# Spark 1.3 and Cassandra 3.0 problems with guava

Tags: maven, hadoop, apache-spark, cassandra, guava

I am trying to connect to Cassandra 3.0 from Spark 1.3. I know that there is Cassandra connector for each version in spark, but s`park-cassandra-connector-java_2.10:1.3.0` connector depends on `cassandra-driver-core:2.1.5`, that's why I am using the latest cassandra connector which depends the latest core driver. Anyway, so far this was not the problem. The problem is the `com.google.guava` package I suppose.

My pom looks like this:

```
...
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0-M3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0-M3</version>
 </dependency>
...
```

I have excluded google guava from everywhere with:

```
<exclusions>
   <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
   </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

so in the dependency tree only this is present `com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0.1` under `com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10:jar:1.5.0-M3:compile`.
However I am still getting the following error:

```
yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {139.19.52.111}:9042
java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {139.19.52.111}:9042
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:162)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:148)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:148)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:31)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.acquire(RefCountedCache.scala:56)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.openSession(CassandraConnector.scala:81)
    at com.ambiverse.tagging.dao.impl.DAOCassandra.createTable(DAOCassandra.java:45)
    at com.ambiverse.tagging.dao.impl.DAOCassandra.createTable(DAOCassandra.java:64)
    at com.ambiverse.tagging.dao.impl.DAOCassandra.savePairRDD(DAOCassandra.java:70)
    at com.ambiverse.tagging.statistics.entitycorrelation.CorrelationStatisticsSparkRunner.run(CorrelationStatisticsSparkRunner.java:176)
    at com.ambiverse.tagging.statistics.entitycorrelation.CorrelationStatisticsSparkRunner.main(CorrelationStatisticsSparkRunner.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:480)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.withFallback(Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/FutureFallback;Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;)Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.initAsync(Connection.java:178)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:742)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.tryConnect(ControlConnection.java:240)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:187)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:79)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1393)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.getMetadata(Cluster.java:402)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:155)
```

Before somebody point me to this blog post for solution: http://arjon.es/2015/10/12/making-hadoop-2-dot-6-plus-spark-cassandra-driver-play-nice-together/, I am using maven as a build tool, not sbt. If you know how can I do the exact same thing with maven, that would be great.

Comment: That is very odd, that error to me seems to indicate that you must have a version of guava older than 14.0 in the classpath as that is when withFallback was introduced.  On the other hand, we had added some validation in the datastax java-driver to throw an Exception if an older version of guava is detected...

Comment: BTW, how to fix it if I start Spark from IDEA?

Answer (score 1):

Although i work with scala + sbt, i had several mismatch between different artifacts with spark, and one among them is guava.

here is how i solved it (dependencies in sbt):

```
  val sparkVersion           = "1.6.1"//"2.0.0-preview"//
  val sparkCassandraConnectorVersion = "1.6.0"

  val scalaGuiceVersion = "4.0.1"

  val cassandraUnitVersion = "3.0.0.1"


  val typesafeConfigVersion = "1.3.0"

  val findbugsVersion = "3.0.0"

  val sparkRabbitmqVersion = "0.4.0.20160613"
  val nettyAllVersion = "4.0.33.Final"
  val guavaVersion = "19.0"
  val jacksonVersion = "2.7.4"
  val xbeanAsm5ShadedVersion = "4.5"
  val commonsBeanutilsVersion = "1.8.0"


  //IMPORTANT: all spark dependency magic is done in one place, to overcome the assembly mismatch errors
  val sparkDependencies :List[ModuleID] = List(
    ("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion).exclude("com.esotericsoftware.minlog", "minlog"),
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
    ("com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector"
      % sparkCassandraConnectorVersion).exclude("org.apache.cassandra", "cassandra-clientutil"),
    "com.stratio.receiver" % "spark-rabbitmq_1.6" % sparkRabbitmqVersion,//"0.3.0-b", //,//
    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % scalaTestVersion % "test",

    "org.apache.xbean" % "xbean-asm5-shaded" % xbeanAsm5ShadedVersion,//,//, //https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/9512/files

    "io.netty" % "netty-all" % nettyAllVersion,
    "commons-beanutils" % "commons-beanutils" % commonsBeanutilsVersion,
    "com.google.guava" % "guava" % guavaVersion,

    "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % jacksonVersion,//fix jackson mismatch problem
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % jacksonVersion,//fix jackson mismatch problem


    //override findbugs artifacts versions(fix assembly issues)
    "com.google.code.findbugs" % "annotations" % findbugsVersion,
    "com.google.code.findbugs" % "jsr305" % findbugsVersion
  ).map(_.exclude("commons-collections", "commons-collections"))
```

i hope it will help.